# Command won't execute via ProcessBuilder "CreateProccess error=2"

Tags: java, string, processbuilder

I am trying to pass the string array to the function to the `ProcessBuilder`. 
When I pass the array I am getting:

> `CreateProccess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Here's the code:

```
public static String[] splitCommand(GitNotifier gn) {
    String s = gn.tf[1].getText();
    String[] command = s.split("\\s+" + "\b");
    return command; 
}
```

```
public static void process(GitNotifier gn) throws IOException {
    String[] command = {"git", "log", "-1", "HEAD"};
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);          // works
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(splitCommand(gn)); // doesn't
    builder = builder.directory(new File(path));
    Process p = builder.start();
    printOutput(p);
}
```

With `Arrays.toString(splitCommand(gn))` string looks like this:

> `"[git log -1 HEAD]"`

With `Arrays.toString(command))` the string looks like this:

> `"[git, log, -1, HEAD]"`

I really am not getting the role of commas here...

Comment: Did you look into the content of ```errorStream``` of the ```Process```?

Comment: I did, no errors from `Process` at all. I know it is a String problem, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `String[]` that gets created by `splitCommand(GitNotifier gn)`. It seems to consist of a single `String` item, that is `"git log -1 HEAD"`, which would be perfectly fine to enter manually in a console but isn't for a `ProcessBuilder`.

A `ProcessBuilder` has two constructors:

```
ProcessBuilder(List<String> command)
```

and

```
ProcessBuilder(String... command)
```

You are only using the second option where **the first item in the argument is considered the executable** and all remaining ones are treated as parameters of the call to that executable. It is obviously different from copy'n'pasting a parameterized call as `String` into an open console, possibly due to whitespaces, but that's just a guess.

It is mandatory to separate the arguments from the executable which is correctly done by creating

```
String[] command = {"git", "log", "-1", "HEAD"};
```

and passing that to the constructor: `new ProcessBuilder(command)`, because `String...` is (or will be converted to) a `String[]`.

However, `splitCommand(GitNotifier gn)` does not create the same `String[]` (check its length, it's likely to be `1`) and that is the reason why the call does not work.